# How do I make a function in VBA to display the date that a cell within a specified range was last updated?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function that will return the date (and time) that a cell within the specified range was last updated.

For example, I want to be able to type in to a cell (A8 for example) something like:

= ModDate(A1:A7)

and the result to display the date in A8 that a cell was last updated within the specified range (A1:A7). It also needs to update when a cell within that range A1:A7 is changed.

So far I have done some digging around on this site and found a Sub that will do this, however, whenever this runs, it does not allow users of the sheet (other people I work with) to undo.

The following code will put the timestamp I am after in column 6, when a cell value in a column to the left on the same row is updated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rInt As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim tCell As Range
Dim tColInt As Integer

tColInt = 6 'Column Index, Example: A=1, B=2, ...... ,Z=26


Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("A2:D43415")) 'Change cell range
 If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
    For Each rCell In rInt
        Set tCell = Cells(rCell.Cells.Row, tColInt)
        If IsEmpty(tCell) Or Not IsEmpty(tCell) Then
            tCell = Now
            tCell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM" 'Custom Format
        End If
    Next
 End If
End Sub
```

(this was courtesy of Asela Jayathissa in a separate stackoverflow thread)

I am fairly new to VBA, and I've tried converting this to the required function described above, but can't work out how to do it. Any help that anyone could give would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Once your VBA code is executed, the Undo is cleared. This is by design. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ffbb5456-bc80-4c05-80f5-fb07245541aa/why-does-excel-not-allow-quotundoquot-after-a-vba-execution?forum=exceldev

Comment: @EyIM Yes, this is the issue I'm facing. If I could change the above code to work in a function, I believe that the Undo history would not be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same issue, I have managed to find a solution to this problem. The following function returns a timestamp that updates on each edit of any of the cells within the specified function range:

```
Function ModDate(Reference As Range)
Dim cell As Range


For Each cell In Reference
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
    Timestamp = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Else
    Timestamp = ""
    End If

Next cell

End Function
```

This requires a value to be present in the final cell in the range. A simpler version of this is (will always display a date/time):

```
Function ModDate(Reference As Range)
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Reference

    ModDate = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

Next cell

End Function
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Obviously you have not tried this code or tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, you can put in A6:

```
=A6
```

Because you already put the relevant value in <kbd>A6</kbd> in your `Worksheet_Change` routine.

Comment: I could do this (or edit the VBA to put the dates in the required cells), however I would like to create a function that does this as it will be more versatile and will allow other users of the workbook to use it where needed (e.g. changing the target cells without editing the VBA). Thanks a lot for your suggestion though

Comment: @BenjyCJ: Just to clarify - your UDF that you are creating there does the equivalent of the formula posted here (filled down of course, and you can choose between absolute or relative (`A$6` or `A6`, noting that `$A$6` makes no sense in this context). Only using the native formula is faster and less prone to coding error. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine

Comment: Oh - and by using the native Excel functions/formula the `Undo` chain is maintained.

Comment: Thanks for your help, although the text I quoted is not a User Defined Function, it is a subroutine, therefore it is not what I was after. Essentially I want to change the Subroutine quoted in to a UDF. This means that if the function was called "moddate", I would be able to type '=moddate(A1:A6)' and the function would tell me the last time a cell in that range was updated. I would also be able to undo any changes (I have just tested this with a simplified "A + B" UDF, and was able to undo after typing it). I hope this makes sense? Thanks for your patience

Comment: @BenjyCJ: You are right, the text you quoted is not a UDF - but your question is about building a UDF. All my comments apply.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. However I have found a solution and have posted it as a separate answer on this message thread. Thanks a lot for your time with this.